# Python - Opc ua with Security Policy

Tags: python, connection, opc-ua

I've try to connect to an Opc Ua server with a python script.
The manufacturer of the machine says to me that I have to connect with Basic256Sha256, Sign and he does not use any certificate.

I use this library

```
from opcua import Client
from opcua import ua
```

And I try to use set_security and set_security_string but in both cases the method need a certificate.

Nobody can help me?